# Add flag for migration to Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, off-topic, flagging

I have a suggestion for a feature i.e Adding a flag for migration to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We really don't migrate much.

In looking at the stats for the last 2 years, we have migrated 3 to Sound Design, 2 to Software Recommendations, 2 to SU, 1 to Signal Processing, and none to SO.

So I don't think it is a useful migration destination to have in our options list.

Remember you can flag for mod attention, and in the custom text field tell us where you think a post should be moved to.

Comment: Yeah, I flagged for mod attention and it got declined beacuse "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"

Comment: And that answer means the mod looked at it and it did not need to be migrated